# amplifying 555 astable multivibrator output

Tags: voltage, amplifier, wireless-charging

I am using  555 as astable  multi-vibrator and its output is a square wave of 7 V and frequency is around 800 kilo hertz.But i need to increase the voltage to about  40 V . What should i do?
Actually ,i want to make a wireless power transmission system.So i need to give the square wave signal(amplified) from output of 555 to a circular loop made of copper wire and generate emi in a secondary coil placed at some distance.[image: Wireless Power Transmission]

Comment: What you should do is provide a proper spec.  This question is too vague without knowing the current capability this 40 V signal must have.  How much current does it need to source at 40 V and sink at 0 V?  It would help to explain the overall purpose of this 40 V square wave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below will operate adequately at 800kHz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq2p5O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 2N7002 level shifts the 7V output signal to 0/40V and the push-pull emitter follower output stage provides more drive current (and since the transistors cannot saturate, it switches quickly). Voltage swing will be a bit less than the supply voltage.

If you don't need much current drive you might be able to eliminate the output stage, but even a small capacitive (tens of pF) loading will slow the output significantly. With the output stage it can drive 1000pF easily.

Comment: You got 4401/4403 flipped.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany my load is an inductive coil.Do i need to still connect the output stage?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Can i use simple transistor(bc547) as a switch with Vcc=40Vdc  and then applying the output of 555 to base of transistor? Will it work or I would have to use MOSFET?

Comment: The small MOSFET I show will work much better at 800kHz. At low frequency either would be fine. If you have an oscilloscope try both and see for yourself.